# Mashing worlds, good or not so good?

Tags: time-depiction, time-management

I have these two worlds in my mind, and don't really want to choose between the two, but have only  time to write one story since I'm not exactly a spring-chicken.

Would it be worthy trying to find a way to merge both worlds into one where both main characters can come together to "fight" against an enemy which has come to be common to both worlds due to some bizarre occurrence?

Or...

Should I just throw away one of the worlds and its peoples?

Both are just as palpable to me.

Comment: There was an anime that did this.  It seemed odd at first but it ended up being a refreshing watch to the usual tropes.  Basically they mixed a typical fantasy world and had a modern day army go through a gate to this fantasy world.  The fights were as if wizards and soldiers with swords never seen a tank before and it was an interesting take/blend.  The anime was called GATE if you are curious to see how they did it.

Comment: I could see either working, too. I like characters, and would pick a book based on that, not how many worlds it has. My daughter (17) loves lots of worlds and I get the feeling this is a trend now. I am easily distracted and if it felt too busy I would tune out. But that's not a function of the number of worlds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. Numerous works of fantasy do this.

Raymond E Feist's Riftwar saga does this. It's a recurring theme throughout all the books, and develops almost exactly as how you've described (with the Tsurani and Elves both fleeing to Midkemia to avoid the Dread).

It's even done on a smaller scale with the character of Thomas/Ashen Shugar, as the boy and the Valheru merge together to create something unique, powerful and capable of standing with Pug (who also is a product of the two worlds merging).

Or there's the stories that merge the seen and unseen worlds together - Jim Butcher's Dresden Files, for example, or Terry Brooks Knight of the Word series (the precursor to the Chronicles of Shannara).

So in short, yes, it can be done and done well. It revolves around the conflict of the two worlds, the fear and conflict arising from dealing with the unknown/unseen, and then ultimately the resolution that combines the strengths of both to stand against the greater threat.

Answer (score 3):

I would really say that it just depends on what your worlds are.  If they make sense, then I say you should go for it.

For instance, me and my friend had this one idea where both of our stories would merge at one point.  In this case, both stories are in the same timeline (mine is in the present-day timeline to 3225, his is to some year in the 4000's).  They way I decided to make it work is that in my story, I sent a probe to the planet that my friend's story takes place (in some odd coincidence), and he retrieves the probe, takes the information, and comes to our planet a few hundred years after my story ends.

I would say that in your case, that would actually be a pretty good idea.  You could start off by giving insight into both character's worlds, then put them together in the plotline.  Heck, you could even do it with some other author/writer, and create a ridiculous storyline, like one of my crazier ideas a few years back.

On a final note, merging two stories for a certain time is actually a real thing; I believe it's called a "crossover issue."

I hope this helps with your story.  Good luck!